Spring AOP Pointcut combined with CompletableFuture.supplyAsync
I want to measure the execution time of methods with a pointcut, which I call with CompletableFuture.supplyAsync.
At the moment, I can only trigger a method, which contains CompletableFuture.supplyAsync, but not methods, which will be executed from CompletableFuture.supplyAsync.
Here I want to measure the startProcess method:
@Async
    public CompletableFuture<Void> myHandler(MyList request) {
        CompletableFuture<Void> result = null;
        for (MyEntity entity : request.getEntities()) {
            result = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> selectRequiredProcess(entity), Runnable::run)
                    .thenAccept(case ->
                            log.info("success ")
                    .exceptionally(err -> {                        
                        return null;
                    });
        }
        return result;
    }

    public CompletableFuture<String> selectRequiredProcess(MyEntity entity) {
        startNewProcess(entity);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(entity.getCaseId());
    }

    public void startNewProcess(InExkassodaten inExkassodaten) {
        //do stuff...
    }

And my Pointcut looks like this:
 @Around("execution(* my.bbb.StartProcessService.*(my.bb.MyEntity))")
    public Object executionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object object = point.proceed();
        long endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info("Class Name: {} . Method Name: {} . Time taken for Execution is : {} ms",
                point.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(), point.getSignature().getName(),
                (endtime - startTime));
        return object;
    }

But it does not trigger the methods, that I call from CompletableFuture.supplyAsync.
I can only trigger the "myHandler" Method.

Please, be polite enough to either accept and upvote my answer or comment on it, if anything is unclear or wrong about it. Thank you.

This is actually a duplicate of many similar questions. E.g., I am explaining the problem and possible solutions here. In a nutshell: Proxy-based Spring AOP does not work in case of method self-invocation, only native AspectJ does. One workaround, if you want to stick to Spring AOP and not use AspectJ, is to factor out the called methods into a helper component.
package de.scrum_master.spring.q78768043;

public class MyEntity {
  String caseId;

  public MyEntity(String caseId) {
    this.caseId = caseId;
  }

  public String getCaseId() {
    return caseId;
  }
}

package de.scrum_master.spring.q78768043;

public class MyList {
  public MyEntity[] getEntities() {
    return new MyEntity[] { new MyEntity("one"), new MyEntity("two") };
  }
}

package de.scrum_master.spring.q78768043;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

@Service
public class StartProcessService {
  @Autowired
  HelperComponent helperComponent;

  @Async
  public CompletableFuture<Void> myHandler(MyList request) {
    CompletableFuture<Void> result = null;
    for (MyEntity entity : request.getEntities()) {
      result = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> helperComponent.selectRequiredProcess(entity), Runnable::run)
        .thenAccept(System.out::println);
    }
    return result;
  }

  @Component
  public static class HelperComponent {
    public CompletableFuture<String> selectRequiredProcess(MyEntity entity) {
      startNewProcess(entity);
      return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(entity.getCaseId());
    }

    public void startNewProcess(MyEntity myEntity) {
      //do stuff...
    }
  }
}

package de.scrum_master.spring.q78768043;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  @Around("execution(* StartProcessService.HelperComponent.*(MyEntity))")
  public Object executionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Object object = point.proceed();
    System.out.printf(
      "Class Name: %s . Method Name: %s . Time taken for Execution is : %d ms%n",
      point.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(), point.getSignature().getName(),
      System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
    );
    return object;
  }
}

package de.scrum_master.spring.q78768043;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args)) {
      doStuff(appContext);
    }
  }

  private static void doStuff(ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext) {
    appContext.getBean(StartProcessService.class).myHandler(new MyList());
  }
}

Run the application to see the following console log:
Class Name: de.scrum_master.spring.q78768043.StartProcessService$HelperComponent . Method Name: selectRequiredProcess . Time taken for Execution is : 13 ms
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@24842b8e[Completed normally]
Class Name: de.scrum_master.spring.q78768043.StartProcessService$HelperComponent . Method Name: selectRequiredProcess . Time taken for Execution is : 0 ms
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@146add7b[Completed normally]

